# Summarise and sum returns no values in R

Tags: r, group-by, sum, aggregate, summarize

```
tenancy <- main_tenant%>%
           group_by(`Tenancy Type`)%>%
           summarise(num = length(`Tenancy Type`), 
                     total = sum(`Number of Works Order`))
```

I'm trying to get this code to count the amount of different Tenancy Types and for each one sum up the number of works orders for each tenancy type. So I want it to output as:

```
Tenancy Type    Num      Total
Tenancy1         121       543
Tenancy2         195       323
Tenancy3         1900      5000
```

And so forth. With the code above the column Num is populated but the column Total all says NA. What am I doing wrong? I thought it was a quite straight forward piece of code!

Comment: You probably have `NA`s in your `Number of Works Order` column, try `sum(..,na.rm=T)`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a table in my question bit on Stack Overflow, I think I'll try and figure out how to do that and it will help, Because the dataframe is beyond large.

Comment: @Lamia that's worked thank you!! I knew it would be something small like that, I'm still a beginner to R sorry, hopefully I'll get better at it.